How to compare two multi dimension tensors
I have tensor of below
import torch as t
a = t.tensor([[[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]], [[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]],[[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]]])

b = t.tensor([[[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]], [[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]],[[[1.0, 1.0], [3.0, 2.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]],[[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0]]]])

ans = t.all(a.eq(b)).sum()

print(ans)

Expected value is 1 as all the values of first (3,2,2) are equal. But it always returns zero.

With t.all(a.eq(b)), you check whether all entries in a and b match element-wise, i.e. at corresponding positions. With your given data, however, this is not the case, because you have two mismatching positions:

a[2, 0, 0, 1] == 2.0, but b[2, 0, 0, 1] == 1.0;
a[1, 1, 1, 1] == 3.0, but b[1, 1, 1, 1] == 2.0.

If you want to check whether any entries in a and b match element-wise, use t.any(a.eq(b)). Also, there is no need to write sum(), as the result of both any() and all() contains one element only.
In summary:

For a boolean result, I would write t.any(a.eq(b)).item() or similarly t.any(a == b).item() (which both produces True).
For an integer result, I would write int(t.any(a.eq(b)).item()) or similarly int(t.any(a == b).item()) (which both produces 1).

